# Where to place electron-cookies?

Tags: cookies, electron

[Here](https://github.com/hstove/electron-cookies) it basically says: In your app's renderer code, just require this package....

I don't know where to place it. When i put it in main.js my app just won't start anymore. I installed it correctly since its in my node_modules folder. Any ideas?

My main.js:

```
'use strict';

const electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app;
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {

  require('electron-cookies');
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600,nodeIntegration:false});

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

As said -> this main.js doesn't work because of the `require('electron-cookies')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to understand the difference between the browser process and the renderer process, reading the Electron [Quick Start](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md), and a brief overview of the Electron [architecture](https://github.com/ilyavorobiev/atom-docs/blob/master/atom-shell/Architecture.md) should help.

Now, `main.js` runs in the browser process, `index.html` runs in the renderer process, so to use `electron-cookies` you have to load it either directly or indirectly in your `index.html`. The direct approach would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script>
    require('electron-cookies');
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this quite a lot and was not a fan of the `electron-cookies` library, in particular for the lack of typescript support.

What worked for me was to store the cookies as mentioned in the documentation like so

```js
session.defaultSession.cookies.set({
          url: config.api,
          path: '/',
          name: 'race-manager-token',
          value: params.get('token'),
          expirationDate: new Date(
            new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 999)
          ).getTime(),
        })
```

This of course stores the cookies only in the main process but to get your frontend code to send the cookies along you can do something like this

```js
    session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders({ urls: []}, async (details, callback) => {
      await session.defaultSession.cookies.get({}).then(cookies => {
        cookies.map(c => {
          details.requestHeaders['Cookie'] = cookie.serialize(c.name, c.value, {})
        })
        callback({ requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders })
      })
    })
```