# Election: Passing Session Cookie to Front end (Backend Functional)

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js, electron, react-redux

So I am quite new to this, and have a tight timeline, so here goes nothing. I am trying to create a login system using express and passport for the backend, and react redux in the front end wrapped into electron. I have the login working for the backend when using postman, but when I am using react the session cookie is not being passed to the frontend, so it is not allowing me to login or stay logged in.

I should add I am also using isomorphic fetch.

Comment: pass the state from backend to your frontend and let redux use that state as the initialState

Comment: @ReiDien Can I ask what do you mean by pass the state, any example?

Comment: first inject the "session cookie" into your frontend code, you decide how. either by sending query when your component mount or by static injecting. like <script>{"mycookie":"heregoesanything"}</script>. from then, you will call redux createStore using that data you passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially Electron doesn't play nice with cookies by default, so the cookie was being passed to the FrontEnd, but electron wouldn't see it.

There are two ways to solve, one for more up to date versions of Electron and one for other versions.

For newer versions, include this in your main render path. (Not in the one with the browser info).

```
const {session} = require('electron')
```

It should allow from there. Otherwise refer to 
[Where to place electron-cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431750/where-to-place-electron-cookies)

Have a hack is not and can post later if someone can't get either to work. Thought I would comment so others know.